# No visible @interface for 'UIView' declares the selector 'captureImage'

Tags: ios, xcode, interface

I have no idea what I'm doing wrong here, the captureImage code was provided in the documentation

I'm pretty new to this, so you're help is much appreciated!

https://gist.github.com/Spongenuity/aa96bb882d23f645f6b7

Comment: Please copy the relevant portion of the code into the body of the question.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error because you are trying to call a method **captureImage** from **LTUCameraView** instance.
But this interface doesn't implement the `captureImage` method.

So either implement this method in that class or don't call this as :

```
UIImage *image = [self.camView captureImage]; // captureImage method is not implemented
```